# What do you call a person or action who provides information irrelevant to the subject?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, idiom-requests, pejorative-language

What do you call someone or the action of a person who in an argument says one thing, but provides information to something that has nothing to do with what he was trying to prove?

Comment: Call him Barry for no reason, that'll confuse him :-)

Comment: A **politician**?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That argument is called a "[straw man fallacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Straw_man)" or sometimes a "straw man argument." If I were to do that to you, I'd make it seem like you said something you never said, something I could easily disprove, then I would proceed by doing so.

Comment: The Straw Man fallacy is more specifically about the focus of the argument - i.e. one changes the premise to something other than originally argued, and then attacks that premise.

Comment: Straw men are but one of many forms of informal fallacy. For example, this could also be well-poisoning, or tu quoque, etc.

Answer (score 7):

The word **sophistry** applies quite nicely;

> NOUN (plural sophistries)
>   [MASS NOUN]
>   1 The use of clever but false arguments, especially with the intention of deceiving:
>   *trying to argue that I had benefited in any way from the disaster was pure sophistry*
>   ([OED](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/sophistry))

However this does lack the connotation of under research or lack of evidence

Comment: I just learned this word this morning!  However, sophistry usually refers to untrue statements, presented using deceitful language as facts.

Comment: Funny how Socrates was executed for Sophistry.

Comment: I was mistaken. I confused it with equivocation. No idea why I confused them; they're not at all the same.